# failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://<server IP>/: Can't contact LDAP server: Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: ldap, openldap

Users are unable to login to network cluster.

var/log/messages =

failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://<*ldap server hostname*>: Can't contact LDAP server: Transport endpoint is not connected
no available LDAP server found: Can't contact LDAP server: Transport endpoint is not connected
no available LDAP server found: Server is unavailable: Transport endpoint is not connected

Can ping ldap server from ldap client (vice versa as well)

Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core) for both ldap server and client

Reviewed and compared /etc/nslcd.conf and /etc/openldap/openldap.conf
on ldap server(source) and ldap client (destination).

Stopped both nslcd.service and slapd.service after Restarting ldap server yet still receiving failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://<*ldap server hostname*>: Can't contact LDAP server: Transport endpoint is not connected.

Do I need to check elsewhere?
Requesting guidance to root cause. Thank you kindly.